# Multiple connections to SQL server with IP address

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, tcp

I'm making an app for my highschool and using xamarin, c# and SQL Server(Being hosted on my desktop). I'm connecting to the server with my desktops ip address with port 1433 and it will connect with no problem.

But when I connect with another application to the server while another app is already connected to it, it won't connect. How can I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant access to the endpoint to listen multiple ports. But first please confirm weather your database is in single user mode or not?

To configure the SQL Server Database Engine to listen on an additional TCP port, please refer this site.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189310.aspx

Comment: The server isn't in Single User mode. I will try your solution and I hope it works. Thanks :D